How to extract all fuel stations (points and ways) from OpenStreetMap using Osmosis?
Currently, I am using the following Osmosis-Code:
osmosis --read-pbf europe-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes amenity=fuel --tf accept-ways amenity=fuel --tf reject-relations --used-node --write-pbf europe-fuel.osm.pbf

Strangely, the resulting pbf-file contains only very few points and multipolygons. No ways at all. See picture:

What I am doing wrong?

Albeit for a different question, the situation is explained and solved here

@JGH That is the solution. Thank you!

Also take a look at osmium tool. It is said to be faster than osmosis and maybe also easier to use: https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html
